Converting Celtic 2D ornament to proper 3D
I need to convert many Celtic ornaments from 2D image for 3D print.
I'm using automated tool to convert 2D to 3D. But every result I'm should edit manually: I make some lines go under others.
Maybe you know some way to automate edit process?
Here is 2D example:


what do you mean by it makes some lines go under others, could you please show the result and why it doesn't work?

As far as I know, you’d need a pretty complex algorithm to detect three dimensional weave from this 2D rendition, but something you might be able to use to your advantage is that the pattern appears partially tiled. If you can find and build one base unit of the weave and then repeat it with an Array modifier, Geometry Nodes, or just copy pasting, doing the connection work between the pieces should be easier than trying to create the weave as a whole.
In case you didn’t know, I totally recommend using curves for this, and turning up the bevel setting on the spine.
